# How to limit observable results to certain number rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have this observable, I want to limit the number (batch) of results return starting at index(lastkey).

The lastkey is the id of items in the observable.

```
 getBlogsWithMore(batch?: number, lastKey?: any, filterForm?: FormGroup): Observable<Blog[]> {
    const filterValues = filterForm.value;
    this.store.dispatch(BlogsActions.loadBlogs());
    const blogs$ = this.blogs$.pipe(map((blogs: any) => blogs.filter(blog => blog.blogStatus === 'published')));
    return combineLatest(
      blogs$,
      filterForm.valueChanges
        .pipe(
          startWith(this.initialFilters),
          debounceTime(400)
        )
    )
      .pipe(
        switchMap(([blogs, filterData]) => {
          return this.filterBlogs(blogs, filterData)
        }),
        startWith(lastKey),
      map((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        return data.slice(0, batch);
      })
      );
  }
```

Let say there are 4 items in the observable array, I want to display the first 2(batch) items. After that, let say a scroll even takes place, display, the next two items, starting from the lastKey(id) of the previous batch.

The above displays just one item then logs and error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (HomeBlogsComponent.html:92)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer]

How can I get this working with Observables?

Comment: I believe you're attempting a pull-based workflow (you decide _when_ to recieve the elements), when rxjs deals with push-based workflows (the observable decides _when_ to push the items to the observer(s).

Comment: Looks like you want to call your function `getBlogsWithMore` multiple times, but you shouldn't call it multiple times because it will create a new Observable every time. You'd have to unsubscribe from the last and subscribe to the new one very time. I don't think that this is your desired behaviour. Also think about what should happen when `filterForm.valueChanges` emits. The newly filtered blogs probably won't match up with the old `lastKey` and your whole blog sequence gets messed up or an error occurs. Just use `array.slice(start, start + step)` to process your blog array in batches.